Assigning to a vector element from another element
In the code below, how are the two alternatives different?
Please expand on the ownership/borrowing flow. I get why the latter (2) fails but why does the first one (1) succeed?
TIA
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3];

    // 1)
    // This is okay. Why? when the next... 
    //v[0] = v[1];

    // 2)
    // ... is not!
    let v0 = &mut v[0];
    let v1 = &v[1];
    *v0 = *v1;
    
    println!("{:?}", v);
    
}


The key is understanding ownership.
The first is shorthand for something similar to the following, which works.
let tmp = v[1];
v[0] = tmp;

The second takes a mutable reference to v and then tries to take a non-mutable reference to it as well, which is disallowed by the ownership rules.
Notice that in the transformed first case, there's no point at which there are overlapping "borrows" of v compared to above where v0 and v1 are both borrowing v at the same time (and one of those is a mutable borrow).
The index-based operations are actually done with the Index and IndexMut traits as discussed here.

For other types an index expression a[b] is equivalent to *std::ops::Index::index(&a, b), or *std::ops::IndexMut::index_mut(&mut a, b) in a mutable place expression context.

In other words, v[0] = v[1] desugars to:
*std::ops::IndexMut::index_mut(&mut v, 0) = *std::ops::Index::index(&v, 1);

As mentioned here, the borrow checker always tries to minimize the extent of a lifetime, so it will likely desugar to something like:
let tmp = *std::ops::Index::index(&v, 1);
{
    *std::ops::IndexMut::index_mut(&mut v, 0) = tmp;
}

As such, the code effectively desugars to something approximating what's above. At that point, it's hopefully clear why there's no overlapping borrows.

I thought the the Index and IndexMut trait methods return by reference. fn index_mut(&mut self, index: Idx) -> &mut Self::Output and similar for index.

You're correct. As indicated in https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/array-expr.html, a[b] is equivalent to *std::ops::Index::index(&a, b). That would deference to get the value and assign in the IndexMut case. I don't think those overlap though and de-sugar to what's above.

There's some discussion of lifetimes in https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetimes.html and what the de-sugared code looks like.

@User10482 integers implement Copy, so they are automatically cloned when you dereference them.

Good point. The assignment stops working otherwise: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d2f1f0629f82ac3d9b828bf9445f1cb3

However, that ends up being unrelated to the lifetime issue discussed above: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=215d61de8922a9bd8daba0bbd2911926

Updated answer based on this discussion. Hopefully, it's now clear.
